# Amused vs Bemused

Tags: word-usage

what is the difference between **Amused** vs **Bemused**

Answer (score 2):

Bemused seems to be confused with amused a lot but they're actually different and not similar at all.

> Bemused means "confused, bewildered, or baffled" and has nothing to do with amusement or humor or anything funny at all.
>
> Amused means "finding something funny or entertaining."

To answer the question, bemused is used to describe something as confusing while amused describes something as being funny.